# Vertx response is sent before session update in clustered session store

Tags: apache-zookeeper, vert.x

I am facing a situation where user gets too many times redirection error, after login to keycloak.

Sample Code :

```
ClusteredSessionStore clusteredSessionStore = ClusteredSessionStore.create(vertx);
OAuth2Auth keycloakAuthProvider = KeycloakAuth.create(vertx, OAuth2FlowType.AUTH_CODE, keyCloakConfig);
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setUploadsDirectory("/tmp"));
router.route().handler(SessionHandler.create(clusteredSessionStore).setAuthProvider(keycloakAuthProvider));
OAuth2AuthHandler keyCloakOAuthHandler = OAuth2AuthHandler.create(keycloakAuthProvider, homePageUrl);
keyCloakOAuthHandler.setupCallback(router.get("/callback"));
router.route("/").handler(keyCloakOAuthHandler);
```

We are using Zookeeper as our cluster manager.

After my debugging I found that, when the keycloak callback comes, in class OAuth2AuthHandlerImpl, in method setupCallback(final Route route), where the callback handler is written, after authentication is success and tokens are fetched, user is redirected to /. Code below.

```
ctx.response()
            // disable all caching
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
            .putHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.EXPIRES, "0")
            // redirect (when there is no state, redirect to home
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, state != null ? state : "/")
            .setStatusCode(302)
            .end("Redirecting to " + (state != null ? state : "/") + ".");
```

Before the response is sent, headersEndHandler is called. In addStoreSessionHandler method, in SessionHandlerImpl class, before the call to invalidate the old session Id and put the new sessionId in the zookeeper cluster asyncMap is finished, the context gets ended and the response to the user is sent with the new session. When user gets redirected to / with the new cookie/session, but the call to update the store is in progress, this results in an infinite loop and user sees too many redirect error.
Below is deployment code :

```
String zkHosts = System.getProperty("zookeeperHosts", "127.0.0.1");

JsonObject zkConfig = new JsonObject();
zkConfig.put("zookeeperHosts", zkHosts);
zkConfig.put("rootPath", "io.vertx");
zkConfig.put("retry", new JsonObject().put("initialSleepTime", 3000).put("maxTimes", 3));


ClusterManager mgr = new ZookeeperClusterManagerNew(zkConfig);
VertxOptions vertxOptions = new VertxOptions().setClusterManager(mgr);
String vertxWorkers = System.getProperty("vertxWorkerPoolSize", "20");
vertxOptions.setWorkerPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(vertxWorkers));
vertxOptions.getEventBusOptions().setClustered(true).setClusterPublicHost("127.0.0.1");

Vertx.clusteredVertx(vertxOptions, event -> {
  if (event.succeeded()) {
    event.result().deployVerticle(new ABCVerticle(), new DeploymentOptions());
  } else {
  }
});
```

Can you please help if I am doing something wrong or this is a bug in Vertx.

Note : I am using vertx 3.8.4 and zookeeper 3.6.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Indeed that's an issue. Filed on GH https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/issues/1576

Comment: I tried with flushing the session before sending the response, but its still the same. One concrete way to repro this issue is, after the server is started, if we delete the data from zookeeper and hit the api, it again runs into infinite loop. From my debugging it looks like the put operation is getting returned before data is saved in zk. Any clue @tsegismont?

Comment: Can you comment on https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/issues/1576 with a link to a small reproducer? Thanks